# How to Sort an Array in javascript by calculated fields like percentage

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How do I sort an array of an object by a calculated field of object properties like percentage of 2 properties of an object like below

```
myArray.sort(  function(a,b){
      var firstPer = calculatePercent(a[factor],a.Total_Records);
      var secPer =  calculatePercent(b[factor],b.Total_Records);
      if(dir ==='asc')
         return  firstPer < secPer ? something  : something

} )
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort 
Just return `return  firstPer - secPer;` and handle case `dir !== 'asc'`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return a number:

```
myArray.sort(function(a,b) {
  var firstPer = calculatePercent(a[factor], a.Total_Records);
  var secPer = calculatePercent(b[factor], b.Total_Records);
  if (dir === 'asc') {
    return firstPer - secPer;
  }
  return secPer - firstPer;
}
```

Comment: The final return is added to handle the descending case